# A single ComboBox column for two foreign keys to single table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridviewcombobox

I been completely baffled by an implementation here. I have a table that I'm showing to my user to edit through a grid. That table has a reference with another table through two foreign keys (pair of foreign keys). Now I have two Data properties: OrganizationUnitId (Int16) and UnitLevel (Int16) and I need to show a single ComboBox in the main grid against 2 data properties.

I'm using the PWR_ORGANIZATION_UNIT_MAPPING for the grid and I need a record from ORGANIZATION_UNIT as a value in the ComboBox column.

[image: sql server view]

[image: vs view]

**Note: UnitId in the form designer is actually UnitLevel. My bad.**

I just can't seem to write a google search query as well. need help.

Comment: Not a UNION, but a JOIN.

Comment: Join? How? I'm not joining the table at anytime. The datasource for the grid and the combo remain separate.

Comment: Seems straight forward you have an object that represents the *Org Unit* and you databind a list of these to the combobox.